# hebpipe library incompatible with colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory

missing modules lib and crfutils.

I am trying to write some nlp using hebpipe library in colab.

After using !pip install hebpipe i get the message that it was indeed successfully installed and even checked if it was indeed installed using: !pip list -v .
the problem is when trying to import the library it seems to be missing the dependancy:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hebpipe.lib.crfutils'

as well as:

> No module named 'lib'

does anyone know a way to fix this? or should i just try a different environment?